# Javascript shim to redefine "const" as "var" for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer doesn't support the "const" keyword. Can I use a shim that checks if "const" is supported and, if not, redefines it as var? I guess it would be nice if it enforced the constancy, maybe using object.Freeze, but I'd be okay with a simple shim.

UPDATE: I want this so I can use existing Javascript libraries that use "const" without modifying them. Obviously, find / replace would work, but it's messy and not very maintainable.

Comment: If it doesn't matter for your code whether the identifier is constant or not (since you don't mind giving IE `var`), why not just make all the identifiers variables?

Comment: @lonesomeday - same reason const was invented.  It documents the intent of the code better than var and, when const is available, it enforces that intent too.  He's trying to use language advantages when available, not just program to the lowest common denominator.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: Added some info - the main reason is that I want to be able to use libraries other people have written without modifying them.

Comment: js2coffee brought it to mind, but I'd like to know for when I run across others.

Comment: lonesomeday - Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem of using other libraries without modifying them.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a server-side shim, so when the `.js` file is requested any `const` is replaced by `var` when the file is streamed to the browser. (Appropriate word-break / whitespace detection needed)

Since you're on the server you can't detect browser capabilities and would have to depend on the User-Agent string to do this for IE only, or have javascript that runs on the client browser tell the server that it needs non-const code.

I do a similar thing with a "userprefs.css" file that is really backed by a Java servlet, building and streaming the file specifically for each user.

Comment: Thanks - I'm hoping there's a way to do this client side using feature detection and defining const if it's not supported. Server-side may be the only option, though.

Comment: Building on this idea, if you're dynamically requesting pages, then you can do the feature detection in javascript and load all of the pages with a suffix: e.g. ?const=false. Using express (and possibly other servers) you can quite easily check of this condition and then do your processing before returning the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Modernizer for this and load the appropriate script file based on support for Const. You could probably write a Grunt JS plugin that builds out the second version for IE automatically by doing a automatic find and replace for 'const'.